# "Shore of another world" vs "shores of another world."

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, sentence

> The lights of Tokyo were visible on the other side of the river. For an instant,
>   I felt as if the city was an unreachable land; a place that existed on
>   the **shore(s)** of another world.

Should I say shore or shores in the passage above?

Comment: Unless the other world is an island, then shores makes more sense

Comment: @mplungjan I updated the question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: On _a_ shore of another world would work

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, I wrote that at first. I think I ruined the sentence with my excellent editing skills once again.

Comment: @mplungjan why the distinction about islands?

Comment: Another world is normally another planet or another continent at least. It is unlikely it only has one shore unless it is an island or a continent surrounded by only one ocean. Of course I can be overly fixated, I guess you can say the shores of Honshu since it has two: Pacific Ocean and the Sea of Japan.
For example I would think you could say "On the shores of Cape Town" since it also has two

Answer (score 1):

The two dictionaries I've consulted say **shores**:

> **shore *noun*** [<sup>Chambers</sup>](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=shore&title=21st)
>   ...
>   4. (**shores**) lands; countries • *foreign shores*.
>
> **shore *noun*** [<sup>ODO</sup>](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shore?q=shore)
>   ...
>   (usually **shores**) a country or other geographic area bounded by a coast:
>   *record companies have been anxious to import the music to American shores*

Both the above definitions confirm that the plural form is normal in the idiomatic expression **foreign shores**, and its variations. So it should be:

> the *shores* of another world.

Personally, I would tend to think of *a/the shore* as a (long or short) discrete and accessible stretch of land, bordered at each end by, say, rocks, cliffs or other 'obstacles', rather than the entire stretch of coastline.

Comment: I agree with this, except I think perhaps the singular allows for a slightly higher level of abstraction than your description. If looking across a river and seeing a different country or place, as in this example, I would definitely use the plural, too; but even if no delimiters or borders are imagined, the singular can work too in some cases. For example, “The body was dumped at sea and several days later washed up on the _shore_ of Ireland” sounds more natural in the singular (to me), since the image is of a particular place/instance of ‘shoredom’, rather than the abstract thing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. Yes, I agree with your example. (I was having difficulty thinking about - and describing - when the singular might be used!